# How to echo the number of reviews of the product on the product page in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am unable to echo the number of my products reviews on one of my tabs.

Now the title of my reviews tab is **Product’s Reviews** and I would like to change it to **Reviews(0)**

I need to have a number of reviews in the brackets.

How to echo the nuber of reviews from this product?

FYI this is **NOT** working for me:

```
<?php echo $this->__(\'%d Review(s)\', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?>
```

Comment: What template are you loading? What block does it load?

Comment: default template, tabs block (tabs.phtml) which is located here app\design\frontend\default\default\template\easytabs\tabs.phtml

Comment: This code is also NOT working in tabs.phtml <?php 
$reviewData = Mage::getModel('review/review/summary');  
echo 'number of reviews: ' . $reviewData->getTotalReviews($_product->getId()); 
?>

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code ( the [code](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/get-product-review-info-independent-of-review-page/) taken from Inchoo.com site ) :

```
// Get product review info (independent) of review page
<?php
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->load($_product->getId());

    /* @var $summaryData Mage_Review_Model_Review_Summary */

    /*
    array(
    ['primary_id'] => 147
    ['entity_pk_value'] => 166
    ['entity_type'] => 1
    ['reviews_count'] => 1
    ['rating_summary'] => 80
    ['store_id'] => 1
    )
    */

?>
```

and Echo this as `<?php echo $summaryData['reviews_count']; ?>`

Comment: as you can see, the output array has reviews_count attribute which is you can use in my opinion.

Comment: This is not working at all ;( . $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->load($_product->getId()); it messed my page and caused errors.

Comment: @james if you put above code just copy paste into your script, it can be caused error message which is single quote between review/review_summary section is wrong, just rewrite manually and try again please.

Answer (score 4):

```
$reviewsCount = Mage::getModel('review/review')
  ->getTotalReviews($product_id, true, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

i followed the code from `Mage_Rating_Block_Entity_Detailed`

as the second argument is set `true` in `getTotalReviews` so it will only get count of approved reviews.

Answer (score 0):

i have found that the review summary count and ratings are taken from the code ...

```
$product=166;//demo product id
        $storeId=Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $product_review=Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
           ->load($product_id);
        echo $val->getReviewsCount(); 
        echo $val->getRatingSummary();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try very simple code It's work for me.**

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short')?>
```

**It's look like attached screenshot.**[image]